# Passing argument through an onchange method in Javascript

Tags: javascript, select, arguments, parameter-passing, onchange

This might sound trivial but I require passing an argument through an onChange() method that I have created on a dynamic combo-box selection.

**Method within which the Combobox is created**

```
function createWhereClauseForm(elementID, fromNameSt,attributesNameArray,attributesDataTypeArray)   
{
   ...
   var attributesListed = '<select id="WhereAttributeCombo" onChange = "getSelectedAttribute($elementID)"><option value="voidopt">Select an attribute</option>';
   ...
}
```

This is what I've currently done passing the elementID using ***$elementID***. But it does not work.

Any suggestions on how I could pass this elementID to the *getSelectedAttribute* method within the same script will be much appreciated.

Comment: var attributesListed = '<select id="WhereAttributeCombo" onChange = "getSelectedAttribute(' +elementID+')"><option value="voidopt">Select an attribute</option>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the variable outside of the string.

```
... getSelectedAttribute(' + elementID + ')"><option ...
//                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Complete line:

```
var attributesListed = '<select id="WhereAttributeCombo" onChange = "getSelectedAttribute(' + elementID + ')"><option value="voidopt">Select an attribute</option>';
//                                                                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently you pass elementID as an string. You have to pass like

```
var attributesListed = '<select id="WhereAttributeCombo" onChange = "getSelectedAttribute(' + elementID +')"><option value="voidopt">Select an attribute</option>';
```